# System.InvalidOperationException: Page must not already have a parent in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Appcenter this exception is happend. i am not able to reproduce this crash.
please help me

App Center Log:

```
NavigationProxy.PushModalAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page modal, System.Boolean animated)
ShellSection.GoToAsync (Xamarin.Forms.NavigationRequest request, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] queryData, System.Nullable`1[T] animate)
Shell.GoToAsync (Xamarin.Forms.ShellNavigationState state, System.Nullable`1[T] animate, System.Boolean enableRelativeShellRoutes)
AtCustomerScanPage.CheckForCompletion (System.String containerId)
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 ()
Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run ()
IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this)
(wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.60(intptr,intptr)
```

Existing code:

```
public async void CheckForCompletion(string containerId)
    {
        if (ViewModel.CanContinue)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AtCustomerPage));
            return;
        }
   }
```

Comment: you mean it worked well on your visual studio but failed in Appcenter?

Comment: Yes. i am not able to reproduce in visual studio.